# Get strings between two pattern (number and by)

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I would like to extract strings between two pattern.

The patterns are:

1. Number
2. Word

E.g.: Give me Top 10 Sales Rep. by Sales Amount

As output I would have:

- Sales Rep.

How I can achieve it with a regular Expression?

**UPDATE**:

The matchDim should be adjusted:
It returns me onl Rep. :-/

```
  Regex re = new Regex(@"\d+");
  Match m = re.Match(message.Text);

  var matchDim = Regex.Matches(
                                message.Text,
                                @"(?:\S+\s)?\S*by",
                                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
                              );

  o = CallMyMethod(
          matchDim[0].Value.Replace("by","").Trim(), 
          message.Text.ToUpper().Contains("TOP")?"Top":"Flop", m.Value);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Wouldn't your output be many values? Sales, Sales Rep., Sales Rep by

Comment: Also, this looks like you're trying to do some sort of neural network with natural language understanding. Regex really isn't the best tool for the job. The easiest solution for you might be to use existing applications (like Google Sheets) and use its natural language processing to do what you want. Otherwise you'll have to try to create or find a natural language processor that will enable you to convert it into something meaningful/code

Comment: Wow guys why the negative points to my post? What's wrong with my question?

Comment: @user12282 before posting your update, it seemed like a request more than a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Get strings btween two pattern (number and by)

```
string input = "Give me Top 10 Sales Rep. by Sales Amount";

var match = Regex.Match(input, @"\d+(.+?)by").Groups[1].Value.Trim();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! appreciate!
But I agree with @ctwheels to use natural language processing, we are working on it, but for our prototype it is enough when we are uing the regex